# Simple IIS7 Url Rewrite doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

at first. I have searched and read here a lot and googling with bing but didnt find 
the solution. In my local enviroment it just works. Iam no IIS Admin so ....
i try the following

My domain "http://mysite.com/" goes to my url provided by my hosting service 
(discountasp.net)

I want that this url goes to the root/mysite/ virtual directory but i want that the 
url stays on "http://mysite.com/". So i defined the following rule, but it doesnt 
work for me.

here is my web.config that is placed in the root directory (generated by the IIS7 
Remote Administration UI)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="mysite">
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
            <rules>
                <rule name="mysite.com" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?mysite.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\mysite\{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The "@Html.ActionLink" creates a link with the virtual directory 
"http://mysite.com/mysite/"

Comment: Please don't use single quotes for XML. Just select the XML block and press Control-K.

Comment: It's possible that your hosting company limits/restricts certain features by default.  You may get a faster response by contacting their support department directly.

Comment: thanks @John Saunders for the formatting suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Pointing my Domain directly on the subfolder and defining a Outbound rewrite rule on iis solves my problem.